# Search for use of :: in nested expression

Tags: r, cran

What is an elegant way of searching through a nested expression for namespaces referred to by the `::` operator? For example:

```
findnamespaces <- function(expr){
  namespaces <- character()
  if(is.call(expr) && identical(expr[[1]], as.name("::"))){
    namespaces <- deparse(expr[[2]])
  }
  if(!is.name(expr) && !is.atomic(expr)){
    for(i in seq_along(expr)){
      namespaces <- c(namespaces, findnamespaces(expr[[i]]))     
    }
  }
  return(unique(namespaces))
}
```

It seems to do the trick for basic cases:

```
code <- "foo::test(bar::test)\n function(x){return(baz::test)}"
findnamespaces(parse(text=code))
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
```

However it feels a bit hacky. Is there a more native method that does something like this? It seems like `CMD check` would need it to verify that all `Suggests:` packages are correctly declared in the `DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it seems hack-ish. It seems reasonable given the requirement.

Comment: Why not do a regex where you find the location of "::" and pick up the longest previous string containing legal name chars? That is, look "backwards" until you run into a "(,),[,],*,/,^" etc. character.  I'm not a regex expert but it should be doable.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft meh, I don't want to catch false positives if :: appears within a string or something.

Comment: I rather doubt "::" is going to show up often enough to cause any significant problems :-) -- but I bet my regex, even followed with a `is.call(found_string)` will be faster than your function!

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#ast-funs for the best way to structure your recursive function.